# Jlabel text alignment not working when used with ICON

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

When using Icon in Jlabel the text is getting wrapped.

1. I want to solve two scenarios, small text with a background Icon
2. Bigger text (No wrap) with no ICON in background

How to align the text properly when the ICON is no longer required.
Also It would be lot helpful if someone can throw some ideas on how to blink the background to create an animation effect.

[As Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP5sc.png)

[text getting wrapped up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUZOT.png)

[expected (Without background)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWfCA.png)

```
package test.client.swing.machine.view;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import test.client.swing.machine.view.ImageFactory.BorderType;

import static test.client.swing.machine.view.ComponentNameConstants.LABEL_VALUE_BUTTON_LABEL;
import static test.client.swing.machine.view.ComponentNameConstants.LABEL_VALUE_BUTTON_VALUE;


public class LabelValueButtonDynamic extends SimpleGraphicButton {

    protected final JLabel left = new JLabel();
    protected JLabel right = new JLabel();
    protected String label;
    protected Object value;
    protected boolean showBackground = true;

    public LabelValueButtonDynamic(ImageFactory imageFactory, String label, Object value, Border border,
                            String imageNamePattern, BorderType bType, int width) {
        super(imageFactory);
        try {
            loadDynamicImages(imageNamePattern, bType, width);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            loadStandardImages(imageNamePattern);
        }
        setBorder(border);
        init(label, value); //NOSONAR needs to be overrideable
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
        left.setText(label);
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
        right.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    @Override
    public void setForeground(Color c) {
        super.setForeground(c);
        if (left != null) {
            left.setForeground(c);
        }
        if (right != null) {
            right.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }
        // repaint anscheinend nicht nötig
        // repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFont(Font f) {
        super.setFont(f);
        if (left != null) {
            left.setFont(f);
        }
        if (right != null) {
            right.setFont(f);
        }
        // repaint anscheinend nicht nötig
        //repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Font getFont() {
        return left != null ? left.getFont() : super.getFont();
    }

    protected void init(String label, Object value) {

        showBackground = true;
        setLabel(label);
        setValue(value);
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        if (getComponentOrientation().isHorizontal()) {
            //          add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
            add(left);
            add(Box.createGlue());
            add(right);
            //          add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));

            left.setAlignmentY(0.5f); // XXX optimalen Wert für AlignmentY finden (0.5 ist zu weit oben)
            right.setAlignmentY(0.5f);
            right.setIcon(new ImageIcon(loadStandardImage("btn_bonus_radio_button_unselected.png",
                    null)));
            right.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
            right.setHorizontalTextPosition(0);
        } else {
            //          add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
            add(left);
            add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
            add(right);
            //          add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));
        }
        left.setFont(Constants.getFontBold());
        left.setName(LABEL_VALUE_BUTTON_LABEL);
        right.setFont(Constants.getFontBoldMedium());
        right.setName(LABEL_VALUE_BUTTON_VALUE);
        right.setPreferredSize(right.getPreferredSize());
    }

    public void showCircle(boolean show){
        if(show){
            right.setIcon(new ImageIcon(loadStandardImage("btn_bonus_radio_button_unselected.png",
                    null)));
            right.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
            right.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        }
        else{
            right.setHorizontalAlignment(LEFT);
            right.setHorizontalTextPosition(LEFT);
            right.setIcon(null);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't get a decent answer soon, please consider clarifying your question a bit more. Also, for a blinking effect, simply use a Swing Timer.

Comment: Also, please consider posting a valid [mre] code post with the question, one that does not require classes and images not available to us. Best to use publicly available images, and to get rid of all imports that (again) we don't have access to. Your MRE code should have a main method, should be small enough to post in its entirety in your question, and we should be able to copy/paste/compile and run it without alteration. The link should explain the details and how it can help both you and us.

Comment: Issue is visible in 2nd image, when the ICON is hidden the text is not fully visible, Its getting wrapped-up. 
Expected is something like in the third image.

Comment: So it is *not* word "wrapping" that you're seeing but rather an ellipses. What are the constraints to the JLabel regarding its size and expandability? What constraints are on the images? Again, please share more details. Again, consider posting code that *we* can run and test. This would be a new small program that reproduces the problem, and again, the [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) link will explain what this is.

Comment: Also, the layout managers that are used to hold and display the label will matter, but this will be part of your MRE.

Comment: `right.setPreferredSize(right.getPreferredSize());` -- huh?

Comment: revalidate(); made it work.

Comment: Great, I'm very glad that you have solved your issue and have things working now, but still, I don't see how any of us could have provided this answer without your posting a [mre] with the question, without having code that *we* could test.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.